# How to retrieve saved fields in database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans

ValidateLogin.java

```
public boolean testLogin(LoginHandler user)
{
    String query = null;

    try
    {
        stmt = connect.createStatement();
        query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName = '"+user.getUsername()+"'";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        rs.next();

        if(rs.getString(2).equals(user.getUsername()) && rs.getString(3).equals(user.getPassword()))
        {
            this.closeDB();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login Failed: Invalid Password");
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login Failed: Invalid Username");
    }

    this.closeDB();
    return false;
}
```

LoginHandler.java

```
public boolean verifyUser()
    {
        if(super.testLogin(this))
        {
            mainWindow mainwindow = new mainWindow();
            mainwindow.setVisible(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

i already saved username and password fields in my database..
how can i retrieve them in my loginWindow???

everytime i enter the username and password.. the message it displays is : "Login Failed: Invalid Password"

anyone help please??

Comment: you need to debug,1st check what does rs.next() gives you .true or false

Comment: i don't know.. our teacher just gave that code to us..

Comment: yes thats why i am telling you to debug

Comment: Use a debugger to find out what the values in your result set are before the "if" statement.  If you don't know how to use a debugger, then try inserting `System.out.println("|" + rs.getString(2) + "|" + rs.getString(3) + "|");` before the "if" statement so you can see whether the values from the database are what you expect.

Comment: can you tell me how? because our teacher didnt explain that code to us.. and i don't know how to debug that code.. can you help me?

Comment: As I said, insert `System.out.println("|" + rs.getString(2) + "|" + rs.getString(3) + "|");` before the "if" statement.  Run it again and see what prints out.

Comment: Incidentally, your teacher should never have given you that code - it demonstrates a very poor programming practice, namely, exposing your database to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: i already put that line before my if statement in my ValidateLogin.java right??

Comment: OK, are you sure it comes up "Invalid password", not "Invalid username"?  The latter could indicate that you are having a problem connecting to your database.  And there are lots of reasons why that could happen.  Can you please insert the line `ex.printStackTrace();` inside  your "catch" block (that is, two lines below `catch(SQLException ex)`).  And if that prints out something when you run your program, then paste it into the question.

Comment: now it displays Invalid Username

Comment: What does it say in the console?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.

Comment: OK, that means that the user name that you typed is not in your database.  Note that capitals and lower case are important.

Comment: yes i've double checked the capital/lower cases in my database.. Username:admin ; Password:admin
but still won't work :(

Comment: OK, is it possible that the `userName` field of the `user` object hasn't been set correctly then?  You could try printing out `user.getUserName()` at the top of the method, just to make sure that it really is what you expect.  Because I can promise you, it doesn't match with whatever is in your database.

Comment: then how do i retrieve for the username and password in my database??

Comment: So, did you try printing out `user.getUserName()` at the top of your method?  Was it what you expected?

Comment: fixed it.. the rs.getString(index) is not the index in my database.. thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName =?");
ps.setString(1,user.getUsername());
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

use column name instead of index value
uname & pass are variable

```
while (rs.next()) {
uname=rs.getString("UserName");
pass=rs.getString("Password");
}
if(uname.equals(user.getUsername()) && pass.equals(user.getPassword()))
    {
        this.closeDB();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: in DB what's the column name where username and password will store

Comment: Username and Password only are the fields in my database

Comment: and in Username = admin ; Password = admin is saved

Comment: try rs.getString(0) and rs.getString(1)

Comment: tried it.. but nothing happens.. it displays Invalid Username

Comment: apke connection me koi problem ya connection string or other if u provide ur connection string then..

Comment: The exception would be different if it were a problem with the connection string.